# How to lock all toolbars via menu in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, contextmenu, toolbar

I am experimenting with Qt Creator and the [Application Example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-mainwindows-application-example.html).

I would like to add a checkable menu entry to a toolbar menu that reads "Lock toolbars" and, when checked, locks the positions of all tool bars. I guess that it is a quite common feature.

I have managed to find a command that locks single bars via :

```
toolBar->setMovable(false);
```

But I cannot figure out how to lock all toolbars.

**Edit**

This question used to contain an inquiry concerning the toolbar context menu rather than the standard menu. Since I got an answer concerning the context menu elsewhere I removed it from this question.

[How to add an entry to toolbar context menu in qt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38035921/how-to-add-an-entry-to-toolbar-context-menu-in-qt)

Comment: I can't see the changes you made. I need to leave now but will try it tomorrow for sure. Looking forwards to it!

Comment: @IAmInPLS I still get the `error: 'm_pLockMenu' does not name a type` messages. Are you sure the code for the mainwindow.cpp does not have to be put into some particular context?

Comment: Did you include <QMenu>?...

Comment: @IAmInPLS No, I have the source code that is here: doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-mainwindows-application-example.html (at the very bottom of the page are all the files I have) and just added your code to it.

Comment: @IAmInPLS Okay, got it to work. But it does not add anything to the context menu. Instead it creates a "normal" menu, right?

Comment: Yes, it was an example for a normal menu. what is a context menu for you?

Comment: @IAmInPLS I see. For me the context menu of a toolbar is the one that you get when right/two-finger/secondary clicking on a toolbar which opens a menu. The default one contains the list of all toolbars which can be checked to make them visible or invisible.

Comment: @IAmInPLS Apparently you also get the menu when you secondary-click on the menu. So maybe it is some kind of more general menu for the application as a whole?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how you can achieve it. First, add a [QAction](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qaction.html) and a [QMenu](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmenu.html); also, **declare all your toolbars private :**

```
private:
    QMenu*     m_pLockMenu;

    QToolBar*  m_pFileToolBar;
    QToolBar*  m_pEditToolBar;
    QToolBar*  m_pHelpToolBar;

    QAction*   m_pLockAction;
```

Also, declare a **slot** where you will manage the locking of your toolbars when the action will be triggered :

```
public slots :
    void lockActionTriggered();
```

Implement your slot. You just need to lock all the toolbars :

```
void lockActionTriggered()
{
    m_pFileToolBar->setMovable(false);
    m_pEditToolbar->setMovable(false);
    m_pHelpToolBar->setMovable(false);
}
```

Now, you just have to declare your main window in your .cpp, and add the menu, the toolbars and the action in it :

```
QMainWindow* mainWindow = new QMainWindow();

m_pLockMenu = mainWindow->menuBar()->addMenu("Lock Toolbars");

m_pFileToolBar = mainWindow->addToolBar("File");
m_pEditToolBar = mainWindow->addToolBar("Edit");
m_pHelpToolBar = mainWindow->addToolBar("Help");

m_pLockAction = new QAction("Lock", this);
```

Now, add the action to the menu :

```
m_pLockMenu->addAction(m_pLockAction);
```

And connect the QAction's signal [`triggered()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qaction.html#triggered) to your slot :

```
connect(m_pLockAction, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(lockActionTriggered()));
```

Don't forget to `show()` your main window :

```
mainWindow->show();
```

And it should be working now!

---

**EDIT**

Your code must look like this :

In the `mainwindow.h` :

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{

...

private:
    QMenu*     m_pLockMenu;

    QToolBar*  m_pFileToolBar;
    QToolBar*  m_pEditToolBar;
    QToolBar*  m_pHelpToolBar;

    QAction*   m_pLockAction;

public slots :
    void lockActionTriggered();
};
```

In the `main.cpp`:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    ...
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    MainWindow window;
    window.show();

    app.exec();

}
```

In the `mainwindow.cpp`:

```
void MainWindow::createActions()
{
    m_pLockMenu = menuBar()->addMenu("Lock Toolbars");

    m_pFileToolBar = addToolBar("File");
    m_pEditToolBar = addToolBar("Edit");
    m_pHelpToolBar = addToolBar("Help");

    m_pLockAction = new QAction("Lock", this);

    m_pLockMenu->addAction(m_pLockAction);

    connect(m_pLockAction, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(lockActionTriggered()));

    ...
}

void MainWindow::lockActionTriggered()
{
    m_pFileToolBar->setMovable(false);
    m_pEditToolbar->setMovable(false);
    m_pHelpToolBar->setMovable(false);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I could not get it to work yet. Probably because I am not fully sure where to add and to delete things. So the `private` and `public slots` go into the `mainwindow.h`. `void lockActionTriggered()` into the `mainwindow.cpp`. And the rest into `int main(...)` in the `main.cpp`?

Comment: No, in the main you should only call your class `MainWindow` (which is I presume, subclassing QMainWindow). Everything I showed you is in mainwidnow.h and mainwindow.cpp. In your main, just do something like `MainWindow window; window.show();`

Comment: Thanks. Now I know what *not* to put into the `main.cpp`. Still not working. I am starting with the Qt Example. So have three files `main.cpp`, `mainwindow.cpp` and `mainwindow.h`. So I have only added `MainWindow window; window.show();` to `main.cpp`. I have added the `private` and `public slots` declarations to `mainwindow.h`. So where exactly is the rest supposed to go? Just plain into `mainwindow.cpp` did not work.

Comment: Edit your question to show more code and/or the errors you get.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a pointer to your mainwindow, you can simply find all the toolbars and iterate over them:

```
// in slot
for (auto *t: mainWindow->findChildren<QToolBar*>())
    t->setMovable(false);
```

Alternatively, you might want to connect all toolbars to a single toggle action, when you initialise the UI:

```
// in constructor
for (auto *t: this->findChildren<QToolBar*>())
    connect(action, &QAction::toggled, t, &QToolBar::setMovable);
```

Answer (score 0):

### One common example with flexible lock options

```py
# Created by BaiJiFeiLong@gmail.com at 2022/2/15 22:56
import typing

from PySide2 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore


class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def createPopupMenu(self) -> QtWidgets.QMenu:
        menu = super().createPopupMenu()
        menu.addSeparator()
        toolBars: typing.Sequence[QtWidgets.QToolBar] = self.findChildren(QtWidgets.QToolBar)
        for toolbar in toolBars:
            if toolbar.rect().contains(toolbar.mapFromGlobal(QtGui.QCursor.pos())):
                title = "%s %s" % ("Lock" if toolbar.isMovable() else "Unlock", toolbar.windowTitle())
                menu.addAction(title, lambda toolbar=toolbar: toolbar.setMovable(not toolbar.isMovable()))
        menu.addSeparator()
        if any(x.isMovable() for x in toolBars):
            menu.addAction("Lock All", lambda: list(x.setMovable(False) for x in toolBars))
        if any(not x.isMovable() for x in toolBars):
            menu.addAction("Unlock All", lambda: list(x.setMovable(True) for x in toolBars))
        return menu


app = QtWidgets.QApplication()
window = Window()
window.setWindowTitle("Toolbar Example")
for i in range(1, 6):
    toolBar = window.addToolBar(f"ToolBar{i}")
    toolBar.setMovable(i % 2 == 0)
    toolBar.addWidget(QtWidgets.QPushButton(f"ToolBar {i}"))
label = QtWidgets.QLabel("Ready")
label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter)
window.setCentralWidget(label)
window.resize(800, 600)
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

[image]