# How to add an entry to toolbar context menu in qt?

Tags: c++, qt, contextmenu, toolbar

By default the context menu of a toolbar is filled with the names of the toolbars. I would like to extend this context menu by an additional entry.

I found an example extending the context menu of a QTextEdit element.

http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/35166-extend-the-standard-context-menu-of-qtextedit

However, it uses the createStandardContextMenu of the QTextEdit class. But QToolBar appears not to have that property:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtoolbar.html

**Edit**

Apparently, the default context menu is the one from the QMainWindow.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmainwindow.html#createPopupMenu

Unfortunately, I have no clue yet how to add an entry to it.

**Edit**

I am working with this source:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-mainwindows-application-example.html

Comment: When voting down feel free to give me a hint on how to improve my question...

Comment: Have you tried getting the current context menu and just adding to it?

Comment: @hyde Thanks. I guess I am struggling with the "getting the current context menu" part. I am a bloody beginner in qt. Can you give me a hint?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need to derive `QToolBar` if you want to provide the same context menu for all the `QToolBar`s in your main window, you just need to override [`createPopupMenu()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#createPopupMenu) in your main window to add your Custom Action to the returned menu like this:

```
QMenu* MainWindow::createPopupMenu(){
    //call the overridden method to get the default menu  containing checkable entries
    //for the toolbars and dock widgets present in the main window
    QMenu* menu= QMainWindow::createPopupMenu();
    //you can add whatever you want to the menu before returning it
    menu->addSeparator();
    menu->addAction(tr("Custom Action"), this, SLOT(CustomActionSlot()));
    return menu;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. However, I get an `error: no 'QMenu* MainWindow::createPopupMenu()' member function declared in class 'MainWindow'`. Do I need to add something else to the mix?

Comment: of course you should add the declaration to your header file. IE, `QMenu* createPopupMenu();` to your `mainwindow.h` in the `public` section of the `MainWindow` class. . .

Comment: @Mike Do you mind that with your solution custom actions will be created for all context menus managed by MainWindow, while OP wants it only on toolbar? At least that what question title and original text says.

Comment: Ah, I see. I was actually not aware that the toolbars can have different context menus because by default they all have the same.

Comment: @Daniel That't should be your decision. Where do you want additional items exactly? If everywhere than take Mike's solution, if only on toolbar - than mine.

Answer (score 3):

You need to derive your own class from `QToolBar` and override its virtual function `contextMenuEvent`:

**qmytoolbar.h**

```
#ifndef QMYTOOLBAR_H
#define QMYTOOLBAR_H

#include <QToolBar>

class QMyToolBar : public QToolBar
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit QMyToolBar(QWidget *parent = 0)
        : QToolBar(parent){}

protected:
    void contextMenuEvent(QContextMenuEvent *event);
};

#endif // QMYTOOLBAR_H
```

**qmytoolbar.cpp**

```
#include "qmytoolbar.h"

#include <QMenu>
#include <QContextMenuEvent>

void QMyToolBar::contextMenuEvent(QContextMenuEvent *event)
{
    // QToolBar::contextMenuEvent(event);

    QMenu *menu = new QMenu(this);
    menu->addAction(tr("My Menu Item"));
    menu->exec(event->globalPos());
    delete menu;
}
```

If you want to retain standard menu created my main window and add your items to it keep a pointer to your `QMainWindow' in your QMyToolBar and modify 'QMyToolBar::contextMenuEvent`:

```
void QMyToolBar::contextMenuEvent(QContextMenuEvent *event)
{
    // QToolBar::contextMenuEvent(event);

    QMenu *menu =
            //new QMenu(this);
            m_pMainWindow->createPopupMenu();


    menu->addAction(tr("My Menu Item"));
    menu->exec(event->globalPos());
    delete menu;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. However, I get an `error: 'm_pMainWindow' was not declared in this scope`. My mainwindow is actually called 'MainWindow'. But replacing this did not help either. I have added the source I am working with to my question.

Comment: @Daniel Of course you need to add that member to your `QMyToolBar` and properly initialize it

Comment: Yes, of course. but do you want additional menu item only on toolbar as you ask in original question or everywhere on main window?

Comment: Thanks. Sorry, I am trying to learn the qt framework. Do you mind giving me some more specific guidance where to put what?

Comment: Actually, everywhere. But I'd be very happy if I get your solution to work as well.

Comment: @Daniel That's not about qt framework. It's about pure C++ - how to set pointer to a value (also if that pointer is member of a class).In my test aplication I added the following line to `MainWindow`'s constructor `ui->mainToolBar->setMainWindow(this);` (after `ui->setupUi(this);`)

Comment: No, you if want the same context menu everywhere than Mike's solution is better