# How to add an action to the default context menu of a QSpinBox?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, contextmenu

I am using Qt 5.7 (C++) and want to add custom functionality like a reset option to a `QSpinBox` (as well as `QDoubleSpinBox` and maybe some other input widgets). This functionality should be accessible via the context menu. However I do not want to replace the default context menu. Instead I want to add my custom actions on top or below the already existing actions.

I found almost matching answers to this question:

- https://forum.qt.io/topic/81946/add-item-to-top-of-standard-context-menu-at-right-click
- [How to add an entry to toolbar context menu in qt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38035921/how-to-add-an-entry-to-toolbar-context-menu-in-qt)

However, these do not help in my case since it relies on the Widget to have a method that creates and returns the standard context menu (like `QLineEdit::createStandardContextMenu()`). The spin boxes do not have such a method.

I also tried to go the cheap way and copy the code that creates the default options directly from source (https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/5.7/src/widgets/widgets/qabstractspinbox.cpp line 1249). This is also not really satisfactory since it uses private members of the underlying line edit.

Is there a (standard) way to reuse and augment the default context menu of a `Q(Double)SpinBox` or any `QWidget` in general? Or do I have to manually re-implement the default behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/widgets/widgets/qabstractspinbox.cpp#n1315

Yeah it doesn't look like we have any easy "hook" for customizing it (and you can make a feature request if you like); OTOH it's not that much code to copy, since most of the menu entries are added by QLineEdit::createStandardContextMenu()

Comment: I ultimately "solved" it by adding a WithStandardMenu mixin class that gets specialized for each widget for which I want to augment the standard menu. In that mixin class I recreate the original context menu as far as possible. Then I can use createStandardContextMenu() transparently regardless of base widget.